# Magento 2 ADMIN login issue

Tags: admin, error, magento2, wamp

We are facing issues after logging into Magento 2 Admin. The login screen came and after logging in, no dashboard appeared.

Instead, this error came up at URL http://127.0.0.1/mage2ee/admin_o0exa8/admin/index/index/key/dbb62ca5c9c5ba2c36eceef7609226751a25f78​...

> This page can't be displayed.

I checked the system and debug logs, but I am not able to find anything.

The configuration is:

- apache 2.4.9
- php 5.5.12
- mysql 5.6.17

I Checked cookies too, and the admin cookie is there.

I believe, right now Magento is working into default mode as we have not made any change till now.

From WAMP logs, below error was found:

`php_error.log`:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Is this error in relation to Magento 2 backend authorization?

In addition, there is an issue in loading of CSS as well in the admin panel.

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should not install Magento on a top-level domain or IP address: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2439

Comment: instead of localhost try 129.0.168.0

Comment: Problem is, due to firewall/proxy settings virtual hosts don't work here. So only solution is to run on localhost.

 

Also on Apache 2.4.4, we tried installing same way and admin is working smooth on ip 127.0.0.1.

 

Is any other solution for same ?